# Does it make any difference when salting database passwords with Random vs SecureRandom?

Tags: hash, password-hashing

I want to salt database passwords and then compute the hash but I wonder if I should use Random or SecureRandom? From an attacker perspective would it be easy to break if Random is used or SecureRandom is used or does it make no difference? if yes why? if not, why not?

Answer (score 3):

I am telepathically inferring you're talking about Java here, in which:

- `Random` is a linear congruential generator with a 48-bit seed and *no* security properties whatsoever, and
- `SecureRandom` is some cryptographic algorithm whose [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) ([archived 2019-03-23](https://web.archive.org/web/20190203030643/https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)) is unclear about its security properties, with broken links and archaic references, but of which one might reasonably expect the following two standard properties:

  - **indistinguishability** from uniform random (or **prediction resistance**, **next bit test**): to anyone who does not know the seed, the output is indistinguishable from a uniform random string of bits; *i.e.*, prior outputs do not help to predict subsequent outputs
  - **key erasure** (or **backtracking resistance**, or **forward secrecy**): even if the state is compromised, it does not help to recover past outputs

    - [edit: I just [looked closer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecureRandom) ([archived 2019-02-22](https://web.archive.org/web/20190202111119/https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html)) and discovered that the one algorithm supported by SecureRandom does not, in fact, do key erasure at all—it just uses SHA-1 in ‘CTR mode’.  Nice, Java.]

***In general*, you should use `SecureRandom` *by default* unless you have *measured* an overwhelming performance concern arising from it.**  *In general*, you might get in cryptographic trouble just from the use of `Random`.  *In general*, you will never get in as much cryptographic trouble just from the use of `SecureRandom`, unless loads of other people are in much deeper trouble already.  **If you find yourself spending time wondering which one to use, but you haven't *measured* a performance impact, you are wasting time wondering and you should just use `SecureRandom`.**

---

OK, you measured a performance impact?  If not, stop reading and go back to the previous paragraph.

What are the security requirements for salts in password hashes?

The purpose of the salt is to thwart multi-target attacks like rainbow tables that save effort by attacking many instances of the same hash simultaneously—that is, the same unsalted hash.  For example, if an adversary is trying to find *one* password $p_i$ given $\operatorname{MD5}(p_1), \operatorname{MD5}(p_2), \dots, \operatorname{MD5}(p_n)$, they can use a multi-target attack which costs only $2^{128}/n$ and which can run in *time* $2^{128}/n^3$ if parallelized $n^2$ ways, even though as a 128-bit hash function you might naively expect the cost of an attack to be about $2^{128}$ in the best case that the $p_i$ were chosen by processes with 128 bits of min-entropy themselves.

Using an *independent function* for each password, as in $(s_i, \operatorname{MD5}(s_i \mathbin\| p_i))$ where each $s_i$ is a *distinct salt*, thwarts this attack.<sup>*</sup>  Of course, it thwarts the attack only if *everyone on the planet* is using an independent function for *every password*; in other words, if *anyone else* uses the same salt, then a multi-target attack can still save costs for an adversary.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) ([archived 2019-04-01](https://web.archive.org/web/20190401024541/https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)), `Random` is a linear congruential generator with a 48-bit seed.  This seed is so small that even if it were chosen uniformly at random, collisions would be expected after a few million choices, leading to identical salts produced for *every* output.  It is unclear how the seeds are chosen; it would not be surprising if it were chosen from the time of day and/or the process id, in which case similar applications run at similar times might choose the same seed.

There *are* cryptosystems where public values like initialization vectors *absolutely must* be unpredictable in advance, like AES-CBC.  Is it the end of the world to use `Random` for password hash salts?  No, but it would suggest that you're a too-cool-for-crypto hipster with reckless disregard for user security and/or your auditors' time, but with ample free time of your own to spend dying on hills on the internet.  You're not that hipster, are you?

**N.B.:**  You should not use MD5 for *anything*.  **For password hashes, you should use argon2**, which has exactly the same considerations for salts, but unlike MD5 can use your available resources—time before user expects a response, available RAM, and additional CPU cores—to raise the attacker's costs.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Using a *secret function* like $\operatorname{HMAC-MD5}_k$ for a secret key $k$ instead of $\operatorname{MD5}$ can also help—here we sometimes affectionately call $k$ a **pepper**—but only if there is a meaningful security boundary between the password hash *storage* and the password hash *verification*; that's a story for another day.</sub>

Comment: yes your inference is correct. what you are saying here makes sense! is there a "best" secure random algorithm that can be used across languages like say both in Java and Golang? By best I mean it will have the properties you described here such as indistinguishability, key erasure and performs reasonably fast?

Comment: @user1870400 There are two separate issues here:  1. Where do you get system entropy?  2. How do you reproducibly turn a seed, obtained from system entropy, into keys for multiple cryptosystems, or otherwise reproducibly derive many outputs?  The answer to (1) for Java is generally `SecureRandom`, and for Go is generally `crypto/rand`.  There are many answers to (2), independent of language, but one popular one with purpose-labeled outputs is HKDF; other options include AES-CTR, HMAC-SHA256 in ‘CTR mode’.  There are also many PRNGs with fast key erasure for (2), depending on your needs.

Comment: @user1870400 But, for choosing password hash salts, you will be adequately served by Java `SecureRandom` or Go `crypto/rand`.

Comment: Got it! We have a service written in two different languages Golang and Java and when a seed is set in one of the language the other language should be able to verify the sequence and provide both indistinguishability and Key erasure properties. This is one of the requirement I have thats why I am looking for language independent secure random algo. so the best is to go with HKDF then?

Comment: Sure the seed can be set by reading /dev/urandom or /dev/random (I hear thats what secure random does) but my goal again that that when a seed is set in one of the language the other language should be able to verify the sequence and provide both indistinguishability and Key erasure properties.

Comment: @user1870400 If you want to do something like `prng.setseed(new SecureRandom().generateSeed(32)); ...; prng.uniform32(); ...; prng.uniform64(); ...` nested in a big computation with state, then you should pick a convenient PRNG algorithm.  Maybe it'll be convenient to use a NIST SP800-90A scheme like AES-CTR_DRBG; maybe it'll be convenient to use a [simpler system](https://blog.cr.yp.to/20170723-random.html).  HKDF is good for using one key for many cryptosystems with labeled purposes by deriving labeled subkeys, like ‘encryption key’ and ‘authentication key’.

Comment: I hear that the `new SecureRandom().generateSeed(32)` in not advisable. But what I am trying to is that if I make repetitive calls to `new SecureRandom().nextLong()` in java and Golang the sequence must be same when the seed is set the same. Not too woried about setting the seed. Sure I understand there are many ways to set seed but I am more concerned about finding a secure random algorithm that can generate the same sequence(same long sequence) across languages when seed is set the same. And the secure random algo must have the indistinguishability and key erasure properties.

Answer (score 1):

A salt is required to be unique. While it wouldn't be a *major* issue to not use a cryptographic random number generator for creating a salt, it is still good practice to do so. I would recommend you use SecureRandom or an equivalent function for this task, if for some reason you are unable to use an existing, secure library to abstract all of this away and deal with password hashing on its own.

Comment: If the only constraint for the salt is to be unique then I am not sure the "value add" does salt bring in? What if my salt is say a short or int but unique. Then I could just do the same dictionary attack that I normally do without salt because the max int is only 2 billion. I somehow feel salt also need to have a much stronger requirement than being unique.

Comment: @user1870400,usually in case of database compromise, we can assume that the attacker has access to the salt used. So for a dictionary attack, we would not necessarily try the dictionary against all possible salt value; only checking the obtained salt against the dictionary should be enough, so doesn't make much difference if the salt is "big" or not. But yes if the salts is unknown then having a large search space helps against dictionary attacks.

Comment: @MarcIlunga Yeah I am looking for that salt is the unknown case and that the attacker is trying to obtain the salt information.  if you agree that a large search space helps against dictionary attacks then salt being unique is not enough right.

Comment: Now the question what if the salt is long(64 bit)? how easy or hard is to do the dictionary type of attack or any other attack(please name it if you know of one)?

Comment: @user1870400 A short salt is very unlikely to be globally unique, even if it is random. A long salt that starts with zero on every person's computer is not good either. Using long (32 byte) salts and a "true" RNG is a really good way to ensure you don't generate a salt already used by yourself or anyone one else.

Comment: "salt that starts with zero" should have said "salt equal to some counter initialized to zero"